# Default HelloWorldResult on ASMX and WCF Service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, asmx

I need implemets a WebService with a specific structure on response, this one:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://aaaa">
   <S:Body>
      <MyServiceResponse xmlns="aaaa">
         <Resultado>
            <ResultMajor>OK</ResultMajor>
            <ResultMinor>OK</ResultMinor>
            <ResultMessage>Success!</ResultMessage>
         </Resultado>
         <CodigoTransaccion>123456</CodigoTransaccion>
      </MyServiceResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Ok! It's fine. I created an ASMX (Visual Studio) service and the response of my WebService is:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://aaaa">
   <S:Body>
      <MyServiceResponse xmlns="aaaa">
         **<MyServiceResult>**
            <Resultado>
               <ResultMajor>OK</ResultMajor>
               <ResultMinor>OK</ResultMinor>
               <ResultMessage>Success!</ResultMessage>
            </Resultado>
            <CodigoTransaccion>123456</CodigoTransaccion>
         **</MyServiceResult>**
      </MyServiceResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I created the same WebService in WCF(Visual Studio) format and I have the same result...

I created the same WebService in JAVA and ¡Bingo! I have a successful result, but I cant't use Java (NetBeans)...

I believe that this extra-tag is for the use of [.NET Framework].
Anybody knows how I can delete or do something whith this extra-tag??

The problem is that the 3rd aplicattion don't run with this extra-tag.

Thanks for your time and your help.

Have a nice day!